# Qt Creator color dialog stays outside the window and cuts into half

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 8.0.2. And whenever I open the color dialog for changing color, the dialog appears to be cut and unable to move it inside the screen, this same happens on all the systems. Here is a screenshot

[QT Creator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCG6y.png)

Thanks in advance

I tried to drag the window inside, change resolution of the display [Occurs on my laptop too].

Answer (score 2):

What you are showing is Qt Design Studio UI. This was a bug [QDS-8018](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QDS-8018) introduced by switching the Qt version which QtDS is build with from 6.3.1 to 6.4.0.
You can either update your QtCreator to [9.0](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-9-released) or install Qt Design Studio 3.9 in a week.

Another option would be to look at the patch attached to the bug report and change the property editor sources in your installed QtCreator. This doesn't need recompiling as it is written in QML.